# Changing Screen co-ordinates

Tags: mfc, screen, coordinates

Just i come across one application.When i load that application,the actual applcation is like toolbar only.Its get loaded in the top of the screen.And the desktop items automatically get moved and displayed below toolbar.Even when i open any other window and maximized the windoe,its get maximized below toolbar only.The screen co ordinates changed to new size.
If before the screen size as (0,0,800,600),after this applcation loading it changed to (0,100,800,600).

When i exit the application the screen changed to original position and all desktop items get arranged to original positiom.

Hows it possible? Can i do that in MFC.

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with

```
CWnd wnd;
wnd.Attach(::GetDesktopWindow());
wnd.SetWindowPos(...);
wnd.Detach();
```

but I'm not sure if it'll work. It would be the first thing I'd try, though.